# Why use Flask's url_for?

Tags: python, flask

I'd like to know the reasoning behind using `url_for` to generate links in templates and the application code.

What do I gain by doing this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
```

and this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('contact') }}">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Instead of hard coding the paths?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From Flask's [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.url_for),

> `flask.url_for(endpoint, **values)`
>
> Generates a URL to the given endpoint with the method provided.
>
> Variable arguments that are unknown to the target endpoint are
>   appended to the generated URL as query arguments. If the value of a
>   query argument is `None`, the whole pair is skipped. In case blueprints
>   are active you can shortcut references to the same blueprint by
>   prefixing the local endpoint with a dot (`.`).

Now, instead of specifying static urls to reach an endpoint, you can use `url_for` which does a reverse match for the endpoint. It is particularly useful when you have arguments which you might want to specify at runtime.

```
{{ url_for('events', user_id=user.id, year=2013) }}
```

```
/events/1388224/2013
```

The paths generated are always absolute (start with a "/") so that they work regardless of the current URL. They also take into account if the application is mounted at a prefix rather than the root (like "/myapp/events/1/2013").

The `_external=True` argument can be used to generate URLs with the server name so that they can be used externally, such as in email messages.

```
View your events: {{ url_for("events", user_id=user.id, year=2013, _external=True) }}
```