# Hosting multiple apps in the same process (flask, nginx, and uwsgi)

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

When hosting apps under a mountpoint (http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Nginx.html#hosting-multiple-apps-in-the-same-process-aka-managing-script-name-and-path-info), i.e: myserver.com/home --> myserver.com/myproject/home, paths are not changed to new URL

The following html files are rendered under myserver.com/myproject/*
**home.html**

```
This is <a href='/home'>HOME</a>   
#<!-- page is linked to myserver.com/home instead of myserver.com/myproject/home -->
Please login <a href='/login'>HERE</a> 
#<!-- page is linked to myserver.com/login instead of myserver.com/myproject/login -->
{{ request.path }} 
#<!-- will display myserver.com/home -->
```

**login.html**

```
<form action='/login' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='username'>
<input type='password' name='password'>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
#<!-- post request is submitted to myserver.com/login instead of myserver.com/myproject/login -->
```

**main.py= flask routes**

```
@app.route('/home')
return render_template('home.html')
@app.route('/login')
return render_template('login.html')
```

**Here is my directory structure:**

```
myproject/
|__app/
|____main.py
|____static/        #js and css are located (working)
|____templates/     #html files are located
|________home.html #page is rendered but relative links are still pointing to old URL
|________login.html
|__venv/            #virtual environment
|__run.py           #uwsgi module
|__myproject.ini      #set mount = /myproject=run.py
|__myproject.sock
```

UPDATE: just discovered difference of request.script_root vs request.path

Can someone help me set the relative path to request.script_root

Comment: please share the related configs and an MVCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't solved this issue but instead, I just used `url_for` for all links which I think is [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436126/why-use-url-for)