# Flask does not render this html file even though the path and endpoints are correct

Tags: python, html, flask

This is the endpoint and function I'm trying to trigger

```
@app.route('/brain', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def render_DBS():
    return render_template('DBS.html')
```

Here is the HTML code

```
<h5 class="card-title">Deep Brain Segmentation</h5>
    <form method="POST" action="brain" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
      <a href="DBS.html"><button class="cardbtn">Click Here</button></a>
    </form>
```

Here is my folder structure

```
/health
    /templates
    /static
    main.py
```

there are other html files and endpoint which run properly
the flask environment is set to production, Does that matter while running this particular endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

`<a href="{{ url_for('brain') }}"`

To not duplicate more, check out this thread for explanation: [click_here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436126/why-use-flasks-url-for)